# TIBCO Error: One Concept file not compiling

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv, tibco-gi, tibco-topic

I am trying to build the project and the build is successful. However when I try to deploy the EAR file, it is throwing a class not found exception. I looked into the EAR file and I am seeing that the file which is throwing the error is not compiling and creating a class file. It is a concept file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try manually adding the missing file on the Resources tab of the enterprise archive's Shared Archive object. This should force it to be included in the EAR file.